# Plotly boxplot not relayouting properly when route changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly in Vue, and the plots are not properly rendering when I visit a new route. Only after hovering will the plot change to its proper size. When I change to another route with a different grid (for the same plot UUID), the plot seems to have some kind of wrong size, and it's overflowing the container. But if I hover on it, then it seems fine.
Here is my code that I use for the plotting and relayout:

```js
  mounted() {
    Plotly.plot(
      this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid],
      this.chartCopy.traces,
      this.chartCopy.layout
    );
    this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid].on("plotly_hover", this.hover);
    this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid].on("plotly_unhover", this.unhover);
  },
  watch: {
    chart: {
      handler: function () {
        Plotly.react(
          this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid],
          this.chartCopy.traces,
          this.chartCopy.layout
        );
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
```

In the options and the layout, I set `autosize` and `responsive` to `true`
Is there a way to make the plot already the proper size (both height and width) without the need to hover over it?
Here is the reproduced example where this behavior can be clearly seen:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-with-plotly-20nev

Any kind of relayout sort of destroys the set layout of the plot, and only after hovering, it becomes correct.

One more thing is that I can't use Vue wrapper for Plotly (it has other issues), so I have to stick with using `plotly.js` library only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Responsive charts

To make the charts responsive to the window size, set the [`responsive` property of the `config` option, which is the *fourth* argument](https://plotly.com/javascript/configuration-options/#making-a-responsive-chart) to `Plotly.plot()`:

```js
// Boxplot.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    Plotly.plot(
      this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid],
      this.chartCopy.traces,
      this.chartCopy.layout,
      { responsive: true } 
    )
  }
}
```

### Relayout

To perform relayout of the chart, use an [`IntersectionObsesrver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) that calls [`Plotly.relayout()`](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyrelayout). This should be setup in the `mounted` hook and torn down in `beforeDestroy` hook:

```js
// Boxplot.vue
export default {
  mounted() {
    const chart = this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid]
    const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          requestIdleCallback(() => Plotly.relayout(entry.target, {}))
        }
      })
    })
    intersectionObserver.observe(chart)
    this._unobserveChart = () => intersectionObserver.unobserve(chart)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this._unobserveChart()
  },
}
```

[image: Edit Vuetify with Plotly (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you use tabs to render the routes? The layout is actually not valid. What actually happens in `User.vue` is that you render views multiple times. This causes the artifacts:

```js
// you render same contents in all tabs many times
<v-tab-item v-for="tab of tabs" :key="tab.id" :value="tab.route">
  <router-view></router-view>
</v-tab-item>
```

Just use the `<router-link>` instead of tabs:

```js
// User.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <router-link v-for="tab of tabs" :to="tab.route" :key="tab.id">
      {{ tab.name }}
    </router-link>
    <div>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And like @tony19 mentioned, make charts responsive:

```js
 Plotly.plot(
      this.$refs[this.chartCopy.uuid],
      this.chartCopy.traces,
      this.chartCopy.layout,
      { responsive: true }
    );
```

That's it! Check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-with-plotly-forked-i2leq?file=/src/components/User.vue:0-202)

Comment: The layout is actually valid. Having multiple `router-view`s is just an inefficiency (rendering the same view per tab), but not the cause of the sizing issue. It's a bit easier to see the problem if you apply the Vuetify styles in your Codesandbox. That is, your solution of swapping out the tabs for unstyled `div`s does not really work well as a replacement for `v-tab-item`.

Comment: @tony19 The layout leads to the a) same page being rendered multiple times, b) causes performance problems and  c) makes Plotly crazy. In my opinion, there are enough reasons to consider it as invalid. Yes, this is not a direct replacement, as `v-tab-item` is not a good companion to `<router-view>`. In my sanbox the Vuetify styles were not applied, in your last sandbox i seen now what author wanted to achieve. in my projects i also used tabs as links, but rendered the content outside the tabs with custom transitions (the part your commented out). This would be the optimal solution

Comment: *a* is true, but I see no evidence of *b* or *c* in the demo. The "crazy" behavior you saw might've been due to the missing Vuetify styles. My commented out `router-view` is yet another remedy, but unfortunately that has the same issue as your solution in that it doesn't cover the features of `v-tab-item` (e.g., touch support, arrows, etc).